# Puppet syntax error at '|'

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I seem to have run into a syntax error on a previously-working puppet manifest. This is running on a local vagrant box with Ubuntu 12.04, and Puppet version 3.4.2. The puppet stuff was all generated at puphpet.com.

The error I'm getting is:

> Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '|'
>   at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:263:29 on node
>   vagrant.example.com

Line 263 of default.pp is the second line of this snippet:

```
if count($php_values['ini']) > 0 {
  $php_values['ini'].each { |$key, $value|
    puphpet::ini { $key:
      entry       => "CUSTOM/${key}",
      value       => $value,
      php_version => $php_values['version'],
      webserver   => $php_webserver_service
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set `parser` to `future`.

Run this command:

```
puppet config print parser
```

If it returns `current`, you don't have access to the `.each` function. To change this, edit `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`, and put `parser = future` under the `[main]` block. The above command should then return `future`.

Reference: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#each

Comment: Another way, more specific to Vagrant, is to set the option in the Vagranfile, in the puppet section: puppet.options = '--parser future'